# "failed to open stream: Read-only file system" when trying to create file outside webroot with php

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, php.ini, arch-linux, nextcloud

I'm trying to setup nextcloud on a RaspberryPi 3 running arch linux (alarm) for a week now.
I've setup apache, php with php-fpm, postgresql and installed nextcloud-testing from the AUR (because nextcloud 17 does not support php 7.4).
apache's webroot is at `/srv/http` but nextcloud installs to `/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud`.
my VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/srv/http"
<Directory "/srv/http">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
#ssl stuff
...
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/srv/http/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/srv/http/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /nextcloud /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/
<Directory /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud>
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When accessing `https://mydomain/nextcloud` in a browser the error message is that writing to the config directory is not possible. The php code to check this uses `is_writable()`, so to debug this I tried (I will harden security again after this is working at all):

- `chown -R http:http /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud`
- `chmod -R 777 /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud`
- directories `/usr/share/webapps`, `/usr/share` and `/usr` have x permission for others
- `sestatus` returns `command not found`
- `su -s /bin/bash http`, then `echo test > /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/test.txt` works
- setting `open_basedir = /` in `/etc/php/php.ini` and restarting `php-fpm`  didn't help

I've created `/srv/http/test.php`:

```php
<?php
echo "username: ", exec('whoami'), "<br/>";
echo "open_basedir: ", var_dump(ini_get('open_basedir')), "<br/>";

$myfile = "/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud";
#$myfile = "/srv/http";

// checking permissions of the file
$permissions = fileperms($myfile);
$perm_value = sprintf("%o", $permissions);

// Clearing the File Status Cache
clearstatcache();

// checking whether the file is writable or not
if(is_writable($myfile))
{
 echo "$myfile file is writable and
   it has the following file permissions : $perm_value", "<br/>";
}
else
{
 echo "$myfile file is not writable and
   it has the following file permissions : $perm_value", "<br/>";
}

// Clearing the File Status Cache
clearstatcache();

$fs = fopen($myfile . "/test.txt","w") or die("cannot fopen");
fwrite($fs,date(DATE_RSS));
fclose($fs);
?>
```

`https://mydomain/test.php` shows

```
username: http
open_basedir: string(0) ""
/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud file is not writable and it has the following file permissions : 40777

Warning: fopen(/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/test.txt): failed to open stream: Read-only file system in /srv/http/test.php on line 30
cannot fopen
```

When setting `$myfile = "/srv/http";` the error message is as expected
`Warning: fopen(/srv/http/test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /srv/http/test.php on line 30`
as `/srv/http` is owned by `root` and has no write permission for others. When `chmod o+w /srv/http` the script outputs `file is writable` and writes the current date to `/srv/http/test.txt`.

Because of the `Read-only file system`-warning for `/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud` I suspect a security setting or default behaviour of arch, apache, php, php-fpm or something else in place to restrict write access of php to `/srv/http`, but I can't figure out which setting and how to include `/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud`.
I guess I could move nextcloud to `/srv/http/`, but I'd rather do this the right way to not break package updates and other things.

So the question is how can I allow php to create files in `/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud`?

**Edit:**
Thanks Nover for the answer. This was indeed the reason for the denied access. Instead of moving the nextcloud-instance or removing the security restriction  of `ProtectSystem=full` completely by commenting it out, I created a drop-in file for php-fpm.service with `systemctl edit php-fpm.service` with the following content:

```
[Service]
ReadWritePaths=/etc/webapps/nextcloud/config /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/apps /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/data
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found from the following link that the Systemd `php-fpm` service may be configured to block any write action on certain folders and subfolders, and `/usr` is impacted by this.

You may want to move you nextcloud instance as you mentionned, or you may also want to edit the systemd service (`/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service`) and comment the line `ProtectSystem=full`. You will need to restart the service (`sudo systemctl restart php-fpm`).

Please note that this line in the service was there for security purpose, so you may expose yourself to some attack.

https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/2756